# Call Python function with arguments using HTML in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make an HTML button where you can call a Python function:

HTML

```
<script>
function login(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/python_file",
    context: document.body
  }).done(function() {
  alert('finished python script');;
  });
}
</script>

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="login();" />
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="index"),
    path('python_file', views.python_file),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, "login/login.html")

def python_file(email, password):
    pass
```

But, how can I pass an argument into the function?

Comment: Where is the argument supposed to be coming from?

Comment: the javascript action, so I want it to get values from a form, and then activate a function with values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is passed to the view as either a "POST" or a "GET" request.

**Your ajax script sending data as a get request. - email & password are fictional, you'd have to get them from the form elements**

```
<script>
function login(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/python_file",
    type: "GET",
        data: {
        Email: email,
        Password: password,
    },

  }).done(function() {
  alert('finished python script');;
  });
}
</script>


<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="login();" />
```

**Python file view function**

```
def python_file(request):
    # if your ajax request is a GET use the following
    email = request.GET.get('email')
    password = request.GET.get('Password')

    # if your ajax request is a POST use the following
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
```